# How do I stop the table from overflowing the screen?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I'm writing a tailwind css website (with js) that can display the contents of a database using a table (this may change later because of the size but I still need to know how to change the table size). The table I'm using is currently much larger than the size of the screen. Is there a way I can stop this from happening?

This is my code below. Thanks for any answers!

```
import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import NavBar from './NavBar.js';
//import LoadingSpinner from './Components/LoadingSpinner';

function Home() {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
    //const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/22570089_Isaac_Wasilewski_CW_RESTFUL/BookAPI"
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url, config)
            .then(function (response) {
                setBooks(response.data);
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(function () {
            });
    },[])

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     if(books?.length > 0) {
    //        setLoading(false)
    //   }
    
    // }, [books])

    return (

        <div className="w-full">

        <NavBar />

            <div className="h-14 bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500"></div>

            <div className="items-center max-w-screen-xl mx-auto p-6">

                <br></br>

                <h1 className="flex items-center justify-center mb-4 text-4xl font-extrabold leading-none tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl dark:text-white">Welcome to the Book Store!</h1>

                <br></br>

                <a className="items-center flex justify-center align-centre bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full" href="/InsertBook">
                    Add New Book
                </a>

                <br></br>

                <div className="overflow-x-auto">

                    <table className="fixed-table w-full max-w-1042 min-w-full text-left text-sm font-light">
                        <thead className="border-b font-medium dark:border-neutral-500">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4 truncate ...">ID</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4 truncate ...">Title</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4 truncate ...">Author</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4 truncate ...">Date</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4 truncate ...">Genres</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4 truncate ...">Characters</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4 truncate ...">Synopsis</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4">Update</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-4">Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        {books &&
                            <tbody>
                                {books.map((book) => {  
                                    return (
                                        <tr className="odd:bg-gray-100" key={book.id}>
                                            <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{book.id}</td>
                                            <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{book.title}</td>
                                            <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{book.author}</td>
                                            <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{book.date}</td>
                                            <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{book.genres}</td>
                                            <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{book.characters}</td>
                                            <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{book.synopsis}</td>
                                            <td><a href={`/UpdateBook/${book.id}`}>Update</a></td>
                                            <td><a href={`/DeleteBook/${book.id}`}>Delete</a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </tbody>
                        }

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    )
}

export default Home
```